# Set system clipboard with multiple formats in Java

Tags: java, xml, excel, csv, clipboard

I know, how to set the system clipboard with data in one format (like text or image data). But I want to write data in multiple formats to the system clipboard. In my application I want to write the contents of a table in CSV text and in XML format (Excel dialect). The problem is, that every call to

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard()
.setContents(new StringSelection(text), this)
```

replaces the previous clipboard content.

Is there a trick, how to set system clipboard in multiple formats in Java?

Answer (score -3):

You can do following:

- Get CSV Text and store in `str1`
- Get XML Text and store in `str2`
- Concatenate: `String txt = str1 + str2`

and now, use your code:

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(new StringSelection(text), this)
```

Comment: (At least in Windows) the clipboard can contain multiple contents, each having a format. I am pretty sure the OP means that, and not a simple string concatenation.